# StackPanel binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't figure out how to bind a collection of elements to a StackPanel.
Nothing happens at startup. The elements are not displayed

Ideally, I want to get dynamically compiled panels with information display. Each element should display an open brokerage account. The information displayed is the name of the account and the amount of funds on it. Maybe I went the wrong way. Please save me

Code WPF:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        Margin="5,0">
          <Grid>
            <Ellipse Fill="White" Width="38" Height="38"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="5"/>
            <Path Fill="Black"/>
          </Grid>
          <StackPanel
            Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Money}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <Separator/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code C#

```
    public class BriefcaseViewModels : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Briefcase> Nodes;

        public BriefcaseViewModels()
        {
            Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Briefcase>();
//Test
            Nodes.Add(new Briefcase() { Name = "Test 1", Money = "10.4P" });
            Nodes.Add(new Briefcase() { Name = "Test 2", Money = "1409.4P" });
        }
    }
    public class Briefcase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._name; }
            set { this._name = value; }
        }
        private string _money;
        public string Money
        {
            get { return this._money; }
            set { this._money = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could be as simple as making `Nodes` a `Property` instead of a `Field`. So, instead of this `public ObservableCollection<Briefcase> Nodes;` try this `public ObservableCollection<Briefcase> Nodes { get; }`

Comment: Also make sure that an instance of BriefcaseViewModels is assigned to the DataContext of the view.